# Popup Background ListView Swipe Animation

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to have a Popup with a background color. When I add a ListView inside, and I try to Swipe to select a item in my ListView, I don't see an animation. It seems that the item is for a short time removed. Just a transparent rectangle. I try it on the Windows 8 simulator.

I have the following:

```
<Popup IsOpen="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Black"/>
            <ListView VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    Height="135" Width="150" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="True">
                <Grid Height="95" Width="140">
                    <Image Source="Assets/MediumGray.png"  />
                </Grid>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Hope somone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have made a mistake in image control source..it should be like this..

```
 <Grid Height="95" Width="140">
                <Image Source="/Assets/MediumGray.png"  />
            </Grid>
```

Comment: No sorry. My code works fine, as far as I try to swipe to select :(